# get selected value from checkbox and put it on a row in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hy all,

I'm developing a web application and I'm trying to use a checkboxlist. I want that for each selected item in that checkboxlist to create a new row in a table.So if I have 5 items and i check 3, I want a table to appear with 3 rows and in each row the selected items.This is how i get what items are checked:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;

        foreach (ListItem item in check.Items)
        {
            str += item.Value;
        }
    }
```

My question is: how can I create a table with the selected values?? I'm using c# in an asp.net application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to recreate this table on every postback since it's created dynamically.

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/30/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-3_2900_.aspx

Here's  working sample code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="check" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Apply Selection" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Table ID="TblCheck" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) RecreateTable();
}

private void RecreateTable()
{
    var selected = this.check.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected);
    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = item.Text;
        cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        this.TblCheck.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //RecreateTable();
}
```

The button-click handler need not even to create it when it's created from page_load anyway.